# Salesforce Webhook Creator - `INVALID_TYPE` error

Tags: apex, trigger, webhooks

I'm trying to set up a webhook in a sandbox environment using [this app](https://www.jamesward.com/2014/06/30/create-webhooks-on-salesforce-com). Using the public Heroku instance works as far as importing all the sObject names correctly, but attempting to create a webhook on any of them returns an error message saying `The requested resource does not exist`.

I've cloned the project and deployed to my own Heroku account so I could view the log myself, which shows this:

```
{"message":"sObject type 'ApexTrigger' is not supported.","errorCode":"INVALID_TYPE"}
```

Any insight into what the source of this error could be would be appreciated, especially if you have experience using this app for creating webhooks.

Comment: I'm familiar with this app. It is an app to create web hooks in a Salesforce org without writing any code. I suspect some kind of permissions problem, but in any case there can be no answer whilst it it closed.

Comment: @Peter it's done

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when the user you are using doesn't have "View All Data" and "View Setup" permissions.  Make sure you connect with a user that has those perms.